# Using Ifstream within a function (cannot access private member declared in class)

Tags: c++, arguments, private, member, ifstream

I'm having an issue while learning C++ in passing an ifstream argument into a function.
Still learning the basics unfortunately, so I haven't had any luck with either finding the solution online, or solving it myself.

The Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include  <fstream>
using namespace std;

int TakefromFile(ifstream gradesinput);
void OutputtoFile();
char GradetoLetter();

void main()
{

    int Studentcount = 0; // Variable that keeps track of the number of students calculated

    ifstream gradesinput; 
    gradesinput.open("grades.txt");

    ofstream gradesoutput; 
    gradesoutput.open("sorted_grades.txt");

    while (gradesinput) // While the file has content to be read
    {
        TakefromFile(gradesinput); //Take data from the line
        OutputtoFile(); //Add it to the output

        Studentcount ++; //Increase studentcount by 1
    }

    gradesinput.close(); //Close both reading and writing files
    gradesoutput.close();
}

int TakefromFile(ifstream gradesinput)
{
    char firstname[20];
    firstname[0] = gradesinput.get();
cout << firstname;
    return 0;
}

void OutputtoFile()
{
}

char GradetoLetter()
{
}
```

The error is within the main function "While Loop", specifically the "TakefromFile" Function
call because of "gradesinput". When debugged the error reads:

```
'std::basic_ifstream<_Elem,_Traits>::basic_ifstream' : cannot access private member                                           declared in class 'std::basic_ifstream<_Elem,_Traits>'  
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\fstream(827) : see declaration of 'std::basic_ifstream<_Elem,_Traits>::basic_ifstream'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
```

Any help is appreciated. And I apologize if this is something easy that I should have seen.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In your function do not pass ifstream by value:

```
int TakefromFile(ifstream gradesinput)
```

but by reference instead

```
int TakefromFile(ifstream& gradesinput)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you pass something to a function, you actually create a copy of what you write between the parenthesis, which is then used by the function. Most objects will not allow you to create copies of themselves because it is not efficient at all, and usually not what you wanted to do.

The & symbol is used to get the address of an object, or in other words a *reference* to its location in memory. You can create functions which actually ask for a reference like this:

```
void foo(int& number);
```

or

```
void bar(int &number);
```

The location of the & sign doesn't matter. Instead of copying the variable, it actually tells the function to use the variable found "there in the memory". This allows you to make function which modify what you send to them. Ifstreams are modified when you read from them - their internal cursor moves. So you want to pass them by reference.

If you want to pass something by reference to avoid copying a big object but you don't want the user to be able to modify it, you can make a const reference. You'll see this a lot later in your studies:
    void something(const object& obj);